# Get textbox value without submitting the form and assign it to the hidden field

Tags: php, hidden

**In the below code i need to pass the value of firstname to hidden field (billing_name). I've tried it using jquery and php. but it didnt worked out.**

Anyone help me out to pass the values of textbox without submitting the form to the hidden field

```
<form method="POST" name="customerData" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/payment/ccavRequestHandler.php">
<div id="personal-reservation-form-wrap">
<h5><?php echo $personalInfoHeader;  ?></h5>
<div id="required-desc"><?php echo $personalInfoDescription; ?></div>

<div id="resform-firstname" class="form-field-wrap">
<div class="resform-header"><?php _e("Full Name","nation") ?> <span class="main-reservation-form-asterisk">*</span></div>
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-field-wrap required-field" id="firstname" required >
</div>

<div id="resform-lastname" class="form-field-wrap">
<div class="resform-header"><?php _e("Mobile Number","nation") ?> <span class="main-reservation-form-asterisk">*</span></div>
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-field-wrap required-field" required>
</div>

<div id="resform-email" class="form-field-wrap">
<div class="resform-header"><?php _e("Email","nation") ?> <span class="main-reservation-form-asterisk">*</span></div>
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-field-wrap required-field email-field" required>
</div>

<div id="resform-retypeyouremail" class="form-field-wrap">
<div class="resform-header"><?php _e("Address","nation") ?> <span class="main-reservation-form-asterisk">*</span></div>
<input type="text" name="resform-retypeyouremail" class="form-field-wrap required-field email-field" required>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $tnx1 ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="555555"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total_money; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkin" value="<?php echo $checkin1; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="checkout" value="<?php echo $checkout1; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="roomid" value="<?php echo $room_id ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="INR"/>
<input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="<?php echo $room_id; ?>" />                       

<input type="hidden" name="billing_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_email" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_tel" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="billing_address" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="http://hotels.com/wp-content/themes/wpnation/payment/ccavResponseHandler.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://hotels.com/wp-content/themes/wpnation/payment/ccavResponseHandler.php"/>

<div id="resform-comments" class="form-field-wrap">
<div class="resform-header"><?php _e("Comments","nation") ?></div>
<textarea type="text" name="resform-comments" required></textarea>
</div>

<?php if ($enable_coupon) { ?>
<div id="resform-firstname" class="form-field-wrap">
<div class="resform-header"><?php _e("Enter Coupon Name","nation") ?></div>
<input type="text" name="resform-coupon" class="form-field-wrap">
</div>
<?php } ?>

<input name="room-id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST["room-id"]; ?>">

<input name="step3-send" type="hidden" value="true">
</div>
```

Comment: Use jQuery for this.BTW if you already have text-box then why hidden? No purpose to do that (unnecessary thing).JUST use POST method

Comment: You first of all need to go read [ask].

Comment: Need to pass the values given in the customer form to ccavenue payment biiling information form.. for that need to pass with the hidden field.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: @maciej jureczko : Yes, I've tried it with many methods.. am using wordpress theme..

Answer (score 0):

If after submit, you can fill it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="text_hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['text_visible']); ?>">
```

If on fly, then use jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="text_visible"]').on('change', function () {
        $('input[name="text_hidden"]').val($('input[name="text_visible"]').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

put this pretty anywhere, i would recommned before or after the form

Comment: please let me know whether i need to add it in the mid of php code with script tag?

Comment: yes.. jquery is loaded.. but it doesnt pass the values of the textbox.. it's seems empty

Comment: Please update Your question and show the code, You can make jsFiddle / codePen.